# How to selectively update a subset of values in Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe, I want to update the values of a certain column based on the value of another column, specifically, I want to do (data is a pandas dataframe with 3 columns ['Depth', 'A', 'B']:

```
data['A'] = data['B'] = 0.0
data.loc[:,data.Depth == 'A'].Topsoil = 1.0
data.loc[:,data.Depth == 'B'].Subsoil = 1.0
```

Then I got error msg:

```
IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match
```

What is the right way of doing this in pandas?

BTW, I'm using Python 3.7.0 and pandas 0.24.1.

Comment: `data.loc[data.Depth == 'A', 'Topsoil'] = 1.0` should do it

Answer (score 0):

Consider this simple dataframe

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0,0,0,0],'B':[0,1,0,0] })

   A  B
0  0  0
1  0  1
2  0  0
3  0  0
```

If you want to change the values of A based on the values of B you could do

```
data['A'][data['B'] == 1] = 2

   A  B
0  0  0
1  2  1
2  0  0
3  0  0
```